# Convert Date by TimeZone

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

In that code above I want to transform a Date by the TimeZone of Server (GMT-02:00) to TimeZone from my Device (GMT-03:00).
But I Always have the same Date of the server. What I doing wrong?

TimeZone timeZoneServer = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneServerString);
            Long time = new Long(Long.valueOf(timeInMilis));

```
        Calendar calendarDateServer =   Calendar.getInstance(timeZoneServer);
        calendarDateServer.setTimeInMillis(time);
        long miliServer = calendarDateServer.getTimeInMillis();

        TimeZone timeZoneMeu = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Calendar meuCalendario =  new GregorianCalendar();
        meuCalendario.setTimeZone(timeZoneMeu);

        meuCalendario.setTimeInMillis(miliServer);  
        Date transformedDate = meuCalendario.getTime();


        return transformedDate;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I doing wrong?

You're assuming that a `Date` has a time zone to start with. It doesn't. A `Calendar` does, but a `Date` is *just* milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It doesn't know about calendar systems or time zones. It's just a point in time.

It's not clear what you want to do with the result - but if it's a matter of formatting it for display, just use `SimpleDateFormat` and set the time zone on *that* instead.

I would also strongly recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in types... it's a *much* more sensible API.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. I did not know the object Date of Java just ignore Time Zone.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in. Inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310, and extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project. These new java.time classes supplant the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar`.

Basics of java.time… An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Your example code uses only [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A timezone is an offset *plus* a set of rules about adjusting for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) whenever possible. But if not possible, use [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

By the way, general best practice is to keep your servers in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). But that's another discussion.

First get the current date-time from your server.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();  // UTC.
ZoneOffset offsetServer = ZoneOffset.of ( "-02:00" ); // Or ZoneOffset.systemDefault ()
OffsetDateTime odtServer = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant( instant , offsetServer );
```

Or we can shorten that to:

```
ZoneOffset offsetServer = ZoneOffset.of ( "-02:00" ); // Or ZoneOffset.systemDefault ()
OffsetDateTime odtServer = OffsetDateTime.now ( offsetServer );
```

Define the desired offset. Apply that offset to the server’s current date-time to adjust.

```
ZoneOffset offsetDesired = ZoneOffset.of ( "-03:00" );
OffsetDateTime odtDesired = odtServer.withOffsetSameInstant ( offsetDesired );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | odtServer: " + odtServer + " | odtDesired: " + odtDesired );
```

> instant: 2016-01-22T22:16:14.386Z | odtServer: 2016-01-22T20:16:14.386-02:00 | odtDesired: 2016-01-22T19:16:14.386-03:00

Those textual representations of the date-time values are formatted by default in the `toString` method using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. You can define other formats as needed; search StackOverflow for many examples.